# Custom Validation Message Component in Blazor

Tags: components, blazor, blazor-server-side, customvalidator, validationmessage

I created a custom validation message component in Blazor like this:

```
<div class="text-danger">
   <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>model)"/>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public object model { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a class:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter {0}")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

then I use this component in a razor page:

```
<CustomClientValidation model=@(LoginModel.PhoneNumber)/>
```

and with an object defined in the code section of the page:

```
LoginViewModel LoginModel;
```

but after running the application, even though the PhoneNumber is null, the validation message is not displayed.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `Expression` like this:

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@typeparam TValue

<div class="text-danger">
    <ValidationMessage For=@this.For />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Expression<Func<TValue>>? For { get; set; }
}
```

Or simply inherit directly from `ValidationMessage` like this:

```cs
@inherits ValidationMessage<TValue>
@typeparam TValue

<div class="text-danger">
    @this.BaseContent
</div>

@code {
    // Read only property to get the base component content
    private RenderFragment BaseContent => (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
}
```

Comment: If this worked, then please mark the question as answered.  No one else will then try and answer it.